# Выделяется ли запятыми "как" в "как будучи"?

Tags: пунктуация, как

Наткнулся на такое:

Я люблю рассказывать(,) как(,) будучи матерью одного
развитого и уравновешенного ребенка, гордилась
своими педагогическими заслугами и приписывала
себе все его успехи и вызывающее всеобщую
зависть поведение.

"Как" выделяется запятыми? Есть ли такое правило?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО:
Я люблю рассказывать, как, будучи матерью одного развитого и уравновешенного ребенка, гордилась своими педагогическими заслугами и приписывала себе все его успехи и вызывающее всеобщую зависть поведение.

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союз КАК заменяет союз ЧТО.

После союза КАК следует обособленный деепричастный оборот (деепричастие БУДУЧИ). Этот оборот обособляется в большинстве случаев, например:  "Было неприятно смотреть, как, будучи сам из дворовых, он высокомерно держал себя над всей массой мужиков". "Набоков в «Других берегах» вспоминает, как, будучи ребенком, влюбился в девочку...".

Оборот не обособляется в виде исключения: "Ваше благородие изволит помнить, как будучи в Смоленске его царское величество о нем изволил при вас говорить". Здесь нераспространенный оборот имеет значение одного слова: будучи в  Смоленске - в Смоленске.