# Глагол + "будучи", запятая

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Меня интересует, нужна ли запятая между глаголом в начале предложения и словом "будучи" в тех случаях, когда после "будучи кем-то" или "каким-то" не следует второго глагола, существительного или чего-то ещё, относящегося к первому глаголу (в случае продолжения первой части, конечно, очевидно, что выделять надо с обеих сторон). *Почему-то уж очень не хочется ставить запятую в первом случае! Если она всё-таки нужна, хочется разобраться почему.*

Чтобы это звучало понятнее, постараюсь придумать пару примеров (простите за скудную фантазию, но хочется придумать свои):

> В Москву он приехал(,) будучи неграмотным и неотёсанным.
>   Рисовать начал(,) будучи совсем необученным этому делу, но проявил выдающиеся способности и оказался самородком.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34917/Выделяется-ли-запятыми-как-в-как-будучи

Comment: В том случае очевидно, как быть, а я спрашиваю как раз о другом. В Вашей ссылке о том, что у меня в скобках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

**В Москву он приехал будучи неграмотным и неотёсанным** (**будучи** можно убрать).

**Рисовать начал, будучи совсем необученным этому делу, но проявил выдающиеся способности и оказался самородком** (обособляется распространенный оборот).

Из источника (правда, малоизвестного): http://regionom.ru/slovo-buduchi/

"Будучи – это деепричастие, и в предложении оно употребляется чаще всего с зависимыми словам. В результате оно образует деепричастный оборот, который выделяется запятыми. Например: Сергей, **будучи комбайнером**, много лет трудился в колхозе. //Наталья писала письмо другу, будучи в Англии.

Запятая **не ставится при тесном слиянии деепричастного оборота со сказуемым**: Они встретились только **будучи уже взрослыми**".

Надо поискать ответ у классиков, но сказанное похоже на истину.

Comment: Они встретились только будучи уже взрослыми >> По-моему, если убрать "только", слияние пропадает и запятая нужна.

Comment: Как раз и нужно всё  убрать: они встретились будучи  взрослыми. Паузы нет, тесная связь со сказуемым. А распространенный оборот уже обособляется: В отличие от великих мы с Норой встретились, будучи уже жалкими развратниками (В. Аксенов).

Comment: Из Нацкопруса: Первый раз я попал в Сибирь, будучи студентом. [Игорь Волгин. По долинам и по взгорьям]. Запятая стоит. В чем разница?

Comment: В Сибирь я попал будучи студентом.

Comment: Возможно, так: "В Сибирь попал, когда был студентом" -> "В Сибирь попал, будучи студентом" (с запятой), но "Был студентом, когда в Сибирь попал" -> "В Сибирь попал будучи студентом" (без запятой)?

Comment: А менять ничего нельзя, здесь важна именно эта структура: порядок слов,  объём слов. Я попал в Сибирь, будучи студентом.  Первая часть имеет законченный вид, можно обособить оборот. А вариант "в Сибирь я попал" незаконченный,  ему требуется продолжение, поэтому нельзя сделать паузу и поставить запятую.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Арина!! Я так же рассуждал, и поэтому мне резануло глаз, когда увидел запятую. Не хотел упоминать о том предложении, которое у меня вызвало этот вопрос, но, чтобы быть уверенным именно в нём, скажу. Читал статью про путешественника Валерия Шанина в Википедии и там попалась фраза: *Путешествовать начал, будучи студентом физического факультета, сначала на Камчатку, по России и бывшим республикам СССР.* Подтвердите, пожалуйста, что **и здесь** зря стоит запятая.

Comment: Путешествовать начал  будучи студЕнтом - вот здесь не надо обособлять, но у вас оборот распространенный. Главные признаки  предложений без обособления  - это их особая (незаконченная) структура и нераспространенность оборота, в этом случае оборот можно тесно связать со сказуемым. Мы должны получить фразу (3-5 слов) с одним ударением на существительном оборота, при распространенности этого  не получится. Вообще говоря, после просмотра Нацкорпуса  мне стало казаться, что такие обороты встречаются редко, а если и встречаются, то народ их все равно обособляет (на всякий случай, по правилу).

Comment: Спасибо, Арина!)

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу причин не ставить запятую. "Будучи" - деепричастие настоящего времени от глагола "быть". Таким образом, имеем деепричастные обороты, которые должны обособляться по общим правилам. Замените "будучи" на "являясь" — и получите то же самое.

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

Последний раз я ездил на велосипеде, **будучи школьником**. [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)]

Comment: Сюда я приехал будучи школьником.  Оборот должен находиться рядом со сказуемым, а предложение должно быть нераспространенным.  Вот тогда оборот "приходится" включать в основное предложение, а не обособлять.

Comment: *Замените "будучи" на "являясь" — и получите то же самое.* Вот именно, то же самое, обособлять не хочется и с "являясь".))