# Нужна ли запятая после "что"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

> Иванов рассказал о том, что(,) будучи в Америке, он обратил внимание
> на то, что...

Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Нужна ли запятая после "что"?* Да, безусловно нужна.

Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после сочинительного или подчинительного союза либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения):

*Жизнь устроена так дьявольски, что,  не умея ненавидеть,  невозможно искренне любить*.
М. Горький
[**Обособление деепричастного оборота**](http://httphttps://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/)

Предложение немного некорректно (о том, что... на то, что...), но на пунктуацию это не влияет (деепричастный оборот можно изъять или переставить):
**Иванов рассказал о том, что, будучи в Америке, он обратил внимание на то, что...**

Некоторая объяснения и примеры есть и на нашем сайте:
[Выделяется ли запятыми “как” в “как будучи”?](http://httphttps://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34917/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8)

Answer (score 2):

Запятая после **что** нужна, поскольку фраза **будучи в Америке** является деепричастным оборотом.

http://gramatik.ru/zapyatye-pri-oborotah-s-buduchi/